# Understanding Openlayers API documentation?

Tags: openlayers, api

I'm newbie to OL (3&4). I found that very difficult to understand its API docs, I believe the source to master the OL lies there. Until now I rely on the examples, that sometimes it serve different method to solve an identical problem.

Can anyone give me advice how to learn this steep docs ( I understand a bit about PHP and JS -but not on its OOP part-), such as a stepping stone to get this interlinked OL API docs become clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were going to start learning OpenLayers today, you need to first understand Modern Javascript, especially the Object Oriented aspects of it.

After that you should have some experience with the [The closure tool](https://developers.google.com/closure/) .

Now you are ready to actually touch the OpenLayers Library. You would then have to go through the [tutorials](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/), and then the [Examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/).

Now you should try building the App that you need.

Additionally, you could also look at the following two books:

https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/openlayers-3-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide

& https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-openlayers-3